# Channel Form Only Showing For One User

Tags: channel-entries, members, safecracker, channel

EE 5.2.2

I'm using the channel form tag to update a channel from the frontend. It works when I am logged in as my admin user but if another user is logged in the form doesn't even render.

I'm just using a basic form to test the functionality:

```
    {exp:channel:form channel="{my_channel}" return="/{my_page_index}"}
        <input type="text" name="title">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    {/exp:channel:form}
```

When logged in as my admin user, the form shows and works just fine. But when another user is logged in the form doesn't render for them.

I was looking for a parameter that is possibly not being applied that would prevent the form from showing to non-admin users in the documentation (https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channels/channel-form/overview.html) but didn't find anything that seemed to apply.

What could be the reason why my channel form tag isn't rendering for everyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no parameters to set these things. You have to change settings from backend.

Go to `Members > Member Groups > EDIT MEMBER GROUP` to find this setting:  https://nimb.ws/YALHnf

Allow access to given member group to add entries from frontend and now you are able to view channel form as another member. :)

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer. I figured it was some sort of setting but didn't know exactly where to look. I appreciate the answer and the screenshot as well!